# AWS Cognito Identity Pool stopped working when idenity pool auth role is changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-identitypools

We have configured one user pool in AWS Cognito. There are no User Pool Group Roles configured. We had configured authenticated access with new IAM role under User Access section in Identity Pool which is assigned to this User Pool. This setup and user access as per Identity Pool Auth Role were working as expected. This IAM Role was assigning access to specific S3 bucket and few permissions for IOT. However, we tried changing IAM Role under Authenticated Access to deny the previous permissions related to S3 Bucket Access to users and changed the IAM role back to the original IAM role. Now after the user logs in, Cognito identity pool stopped working and started throwing 403 Forbidden Error. It looks like changing back to the original IAM Role is not working anymore. All these operations are done via AWS Console. We can't recreate User Pool. How can we debug and solve this issue?

Comment: Check CloudTrail, what request is actually not working and why? What is the "auth role" you are referring to, that term does not exist / has no defined meaning. What changes did you perform, what permissions, what policies? Did you change stuff via the CLI, via the UI or e.g. via IaC via CDK or TF?

Comment: Hi @luk2302, I have edited the question to add information as you asked. I will check CloudTrail to get more insights

Comment: Almost exactly the same thing here. We added a policy to our users, which revokes all permissions unless you have MFA activated.
Users were not notified about activating MFA & even after enabling MFA, services created like Cognito app's, we're all returning 403's because the said user didn't have the permission.